# Recognize sets of numbers in collection of sets

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, set

I have a collection of sets with numbers in it. Say

```
A = {-2, 5, 6, 8}  
B = {-2, 4}  
C = {-2, 4, 6, 8}  
D = {1, -2, 15}  
E = {1, 4, 15}  
F = {1, 15}  
G = {2, 5, 6, 15}  
H = {2, 6, 15}
```

Now I want to find a set of 4 numbers and find the sets which belong to this set.
For instance, I can define a set here `X = {1, -2, 4, 15}` and one sees that B, D, E and F belong to this set. Finding these sets is not very difficult.

However, the problem I am facing is that I want to identify all sets with a length of m numbers within this collection. So in fact, when taking the above example as input, an algorithm that gets `m = 4`, and `{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}` as inputs and gives me `{B,D,E,F}` and `{B, C}` (since they all contain numbers in the set {-2, -4, 6, 8}).

The only way I could come up with the answer was to generate all sets of `length = 4` possible with the numbers in the sets available and identify whether or not every set fits. This seems a bit blunt.

Any good tips? (Java or PHP)?

Comment: E and F don't contain any of {-2,-4,6,8}, so why should they be returned?

Comment: You want to find minimum number of sets of length 4? and output them?

Comment: Shouldn't output be the following: {A}, {B, C}, {B, D, E, F}, {B, E, F}, {D, E, F}, {F, H}, {G, H}?

Comment: @Dialecticus: You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this problem recursively. Consider one set. If taking elements from this set will bring number of elements larger than m then consider next set. Take elements from this set. If there are no more sets to consider then you have some set of sets as a possible result. If number of elements in this result is equal m, then take this result. Now "unconsider" last considered set, and consider next set. Repeat until there are no more sets to consider. In the end remove all results that are subsets of existing results.

Comment: I like this approach and will try to implement it

Answer (score 1):

In Java you could use the `retainAll()` method of collections or the static method `Collections.disjoint(a,b)` to either find the elements that are contained in both or just check if they have common elements.

Example:

```
Set<Integer> setA = new HashSet<Integer>();
setA.add( -2 );
setA.add( 5 );
setA.add( 6 );
setA.add( 8 );

Set<Integer> setB = new HashSet<Integer>();
setB.add( -2 );
setB.add( -4 );
setB.add( 6 );
setB.add( 8 );

//fill with all values from setA
HashSet<Integer> setAB = new HashSet<Integer>( setA );
//keep only those values that are contained in setB as well
setAB.retainAll( setB );


System.out.println( setAB ); //prints "[-2, 8, 6]"

System.out.println( "A and B overlap: " + !Collections.disjoint( setA, setB ) ); //prints "A and B overlap: true"
```

If you have a collection of sets e.g. `List<Set<Integer>>` iterate over them and compare each one to the input set.

Alternatively you could use the Apache Commons Collections class `CollectionUtils` which provides handy methods like `CollectionUtils.containsAny( collection1,collection2 )` or `CollectionUtils.union( collection1,collection2 )`.

Google Guava might have a similar class as well.